# Docker how to start container with defined nameservers in /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, nameservers

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM javamachine_0.1.2
MAINTAINER Meiram
RUN /report/report.sh start
ENV LANG C.UTF-8 ENV LANGUAGE C.UTF-8 ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
RUN echo "nameserver 192.168.1.100" > /etc/resolv.conf
COPY resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
EXPOSE 9090
```

when creating container directive docker run --dns also do not change entries in /etc/resolv.conf

How to change entries in /etc/resolv.conf permanently?

Comment: Take a look at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672193/curl-command-returns-nothing-in-dockerfile-whilst-it-works-in-every-other-linu) and the answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you use docker-compose you can simple add your dns-server in docker-compose.yml

```
  my-app:
     build: my-app
     dns:
       - 10.20.20.1  # dns server 1
       - 10.21.21.2  # dns server 2
     dns_search: ibm-edv.ibmnet.int
```

see https://bitbucket.org/snippets/mountdiablo/9yKxG/docker-compose-reference-yaml-file-with

Answer (score 3):

if you use --dns you may need to remove those lines:

```
RUN echo "nameserver 192.168.1.100" > /etc/resolv.conf
COPY resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

also,

try to swap the lines too.. COPY command will override the previous one.

Comment: I rebuild the image with Dockerfile.
I wiped 2 line 
RUN echo "nameserver 192.168.1.100" > /etc/resolv.conf
COPY resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

docker run --dns 8.8.8.8  test/test_img_0.1.2 

But container can not to start.

Comment: I don't know maybe it

when I create container 

docker run  --dns 8.8.8.8 -td ubunu:latest 

It's ok. 

But I need to create container with existing network and static ip

docker run --net my_net --dns 8.8.8.8 --ip 10.10.10.10 -td ubuntu:latest 

/etc/resolv.conf entries are 

nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0

Comment: Just a comment: all docker official resources (and unofficial) seems to urge one NOT to tamper directly with resolv.conf - docker engine is supposed to manager that (same goes for /etc/hosts). I believe you can achieve the above with `--dns` option to either docker eninge or container run time.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer

When you need to create a container with default network settings (172.0.0.x)

The key **--dns** is working. **But doesn't work with user-defined network --net some_name_of_your_network**

So if you need to create container you can define hostnames in /etc/hosts

using this command

```
docker run --net my_net --ip 192.168.1.x --add-host webserver:192.168.1.100 --add-host mysqlserver:192.168.1.x -td someimage
```

But this solution is not acceptable for me. Because I need to edit /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 2):

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/ for more details.

You'll want to add the following to your docker command line, instead of all the `--add-host` options (assuming that your hosts are resolvable through your dns)

```
--dns=192.168.1.100
```

Based on the fact that you're running multiple services, if your webserver and mysqlserver are also docker containers, you might want to configure the collection of containers via docker-compose.  See https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/ for more details.

Comment: What if you need to set multiple nameservers? I'm trying to set two, for instance.

Comment: Turns out the answer is just to repeat the flag, sorry. See [Github](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5435). In this instance,`--dns=192.168.1.100 --dns=192.168.1.101` would work.

Answer (score 0):

### [DNS services](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services)

`--dns IP`

> The IP address of a DNS server. To specify multiple DNS servers, use multiple --dns flags. If the container cannot reach any of the IP addresses you specify, Google’s public DNS server 8.8.8.8 is added, so that your container can resolve internet domains.

#### NOTE

That if we pass IP address to `--dns` option still `/etc/resolv.conf` nameserver is as before; because Docker uses default embedded DNS server and the value of `--dns` is set for that network.

#### Example

we can run CoreDNS this way:

```
docker container run --rm -it -v  $PWD:/root/ --network mybr --ip 10.11.12.244  coredns/coredns:latest -dns.port 53 -conf /root/coredns
```

So our DNS server is up and running on `--ip 10.11.12.244`

At the same time we can run another container on the network (custom-defined) and check for some records .

```
docker container run --rm -it --network mybr --ip 10.11.12.11 --dns 10.11.12.244   nicolaka/netshoot bash
```

So by passing `--dns 10.11.12.244` inside that container still we see the default one which is not right.

```
bash-5.1# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

And test it

```
bash-5.1# dig node.examp1e.ir @10.11.12.244 +nocmd +nostats +nocomments
;node.examp1e.ir.       IN  A
node.examp1e.ir.    3600    IN  A   10.11.12.10
examp1e.ir.     3600    IN  NS  a.ns.examp1e.ir.
examp1e.ir.     3600    IN  NS  b.ns.examp1e.ir.
bash-5.1#
bash-5.1#
bash-5.1#
bash-5.1# dig node.examp1e.ir  +nocmd +nostats +nocomments
;node.examp1e.ir.       IN  A
node.examp1e.ir.    3600    IN  A   10.11.12.10
examp1e.ir.     3600    IN  NS  a.ns.examp1e.ir.
examp1e.ir.     3600    IN  NS  b.ns.examp1e.ir.
bash-5.1#
```

and here is the config and zone for examp1e.ir

```
examp1e.ir {
    file /root/db.10.11.12.0
    log
    errors
}
```

And *db.10.11.12.0*

```
$TTL    3600
@   IN  SOA a.ns.examp1e.ir. webmaster.examp1e.ir. (
                  3     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  a.ns.examp1e.ir.
@   IN  NS  b.ns.examp1e.ir.
a.ns    IN  A   10.11.12.244
b.ns    IN  A   10.11.12.244

node        IN  A  10.11.12.10
nginx       IN  A  10.11.12.11
nginx       IN  TXT "this is nginx design pattern"
```

---

`mybr` is a custom defined network

```
docker network ls | grep mybr
02884d702083   mybr                     bridge    local
```

and `... inspect mybr`

```
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": {},
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "10.11.12.0/24",
                "Gateway": "10.11.12.1"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Just bind container volume, with the volume, inside a container,
E.g. Make a file on host machine `resolv.conf`, and then bind it with `/etc/resolv.conf` inside the container.
It worked for me