# `curl` command returns nothing in Dockerfile whilst it works in every other linux system

Tags: curl, docker, dockerfile

I have a Docker file containing:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Zeinab Abbasimazar
RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y wget unzip curl aptitude
RUN aptitude search curl
RUN VERSION=$(curl myURL 2>&1 | grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)"' | cut -d'"' -f2 | egrep component-[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]$ | cut -d'-' -f3); echo $VERSION
```

Last line command echos version as expected in any linux command line if `curl` is installed, but during docker build no version is returned.

Comment: It did not return anything on my system too :/

Comment: @Ayushya, this command is customized based on my need. You don't have sufficient information to get results. The main issue is that it works on a normal shell, but doesn't work in a `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Add a debugging step before `RUN curl -v myURL` and see what you get?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, your comment led me to a way that saved me a lot of time. It was all about my `resolv.conf` file which wasn't set properly and curl was not able to access the URL; but since I used some `cut` and `grep` command ahead of that, I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi, do list your solution also, so others are helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TarunLalwani's comment led me to a way that saved me a lot of time.

It was all about my `resolv.conf` file which wasn't set properly and curl was not able to access the URL; but since I used some `cut` and `grep` command ahead of that, I couldn't figure it out.

I googled and I found out that I should set my desired configurations for `resolve.conf`, then execute `curl` in one `RUN` command in order to be able to resolve the URL ([described here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25537#issuecomment-238582080)).

I have this `Dockerfile` now, which works fine:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Zeinab Abbasimazar
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN echo "nameserver myDNS\n" > /etc/resolv.conf; \
    export VERSION=$(curl myURL 2>&1 | grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)"' | cut -d'"' -f2 | egrep component-[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]$ | cut -d'-' -f3); \
    echo $VERSION
```