# yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only\n safe thing yum can do is fail

Tags: centos, yum

We use custom yum repos at our company. Something is causing them to fail the `yum makecache` command.

I'm on `CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)`.

Here's the error that we get when we run `yum makecache`:

```
 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this
```

The repos look like this and I need to use both of them.

Epel repo:

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch/debug
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-7&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/SRPMS
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-7&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
gpgcheck=1
```

Our company repo:

```
[mmp]
name=MMP
baseurl=http://10.245.19.168/mmp_repo/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. How can I make this error go away?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [centos 7.1 - error repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524675/centos-7-1-error-repository)

Comment: If you aren't using the `EPEL` repos you should disable it; If you are then you need to uncomment the baseurl's of them in the config.

Comment: I need to use both repos, but still getting the error. I tried moving the mmp repo out of the yum repos directory and uncommented the base url of the epel repo. 

That didn't work. I get the same error after running the `yum makecache` command. 

How can I get both repos working with the `yum makecache` command?

Comment: what is the output of `yum makecache -v`? does it indicate any clues if you step it up to `yum makecache -v  -d5 -e5`?

Comment: It might help if you post the output of the command `yum-config-manager`; it should give more insight into what is happening. How did you setup your company repo, and does `yum makecache` work if you disable it or the epel repo, or the vice versa?

Comment: I disagree with the output. There must be safer things yum can do than failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is solved [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/yum-doesn-t-have-enough-cached-data-to-continue/m-p/220863/highlight/true#M182737). So, first, some background: When yum installs a package, it unpacks and moves all of the files to the proper directory (i.e. `opt`, `bin`, `etc` etcetera). When a network connection is interrupted, a drive-write is stopped, what have you, during the install process, some files might not be written, while the program still returns that it was installed successfully.

> To fix this:

On the host where the installation is failing, check if the repos are correct.

Especially the baseurl

`# grep 'baseurl' /etc/yum.repos.d/* | grep HDP`

Just append "/repodata/repomd.xml" in the URL and then test if it is accessible.

Example: if baseurl is `http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/2.x/updates/2.6.3.0` then try accessing it as following to verify the access. Please check all the URLs

`# curl -v http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/2.x/updates/2.6.3.0/repodata/repomd.xml`

If the URLs are accessible then in that case try cleaning the yum cache by running the command.

`# yum clean all`

After yum clean try running the following command again to verify if the issue persist.

`# yum -y install ranger_2_6_3_0_235-admin`

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a problem with the EPEL repository. Try yum with

```
--disablerepo=epel\*
```

until they get this fixed.

if you don't have an immediate need to get packages from EPEL, use yum with

```
--disablerepo=epel
```

until your local mirror syncs. yum clean all may or may not help, depending on which mirror you hit.

My general suggestion is still valid, though -- unless you have an immediate need to get EPEL packages, I would suggest using

```
--disablerepo=epel
```

until your local mirror gets the fixed repodata. If you do have an immediate need for EPEL packages and

```
 yum clean all
```

does not help, you will need to adjust your config to point to some specific mirror that has the fixed content, like by adding baseurl=http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/7/

**$basearch    to epel.repo. Most mirrors should be updated by now, though.**

---

## Alternatives >>>

I happened to be on Freenode channel #epel when someone complained about this issue, but if this had happened to me, I could have enabled one repository at a time **(with --disablerepo=* and --enablerepo=somerepo)** to find which repo caused the trouble.

**skip_if_unavailable=1 for non-critical repos sounds like a good idea.**

Many people need only a few packages from EPEL. One option would be to import the EPEL packages you need to some locally controlled repository and use that instead. createrepo is related to this.
Top

Comment: This is just telling him how to get around the error, not fix the issue.

Comment: This solution helped me - remove epel: `yum remove epel-release` , then, as the author of the answer advises, clear the cache

Answer (score 1):

Check your network connectivity. If you can't see your system ip address, then you should check & make network connectivity properly.

I faced this issue. I used CentOS 7 in VM ware. If I execute "ifconfig" command, it will show one IP address only. But generally in VM ware it should show two ip addresses. So if you can see only one IP address, then shutdown your linux system. Then change your Network Settings (Network Adapter) in VM ware.

Try this, it will work...!